# Why does IE7 set a width of 100% and wrap <LI> elements?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, html-lists, internet-explorer-6

This works fine in chrome and firefox but IE7 wraps each LI item.

I can set a width on the li items which fixes the problem however, the width is variable on each item and I would prefer a "cleaner" solution...

What am I missing?

CSS:

```
.container {
  height: 200px;
}
.container ul {
  display: block;
}
.container ul li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
.container ul li a {
  font-family: Arial;
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 9px 0 9px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;   
}
.container ul li a:hover {
  border: 2px solid rgb(227, 227, 227);
  background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(white),to(rgb(243, 243, 243)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,white,rgb(243, 243, 243));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,white,rgb(243, 243, 243));
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,white,rgb(243, 243, 243));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,white,rgb(243, 243, 243));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,white,rgb(243, 243, 243));
}
.container ul li a .name {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgb(0, 23, 58);
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 22px 0 0 0;
}
.container ul li a .more {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgb(0, 23, 58);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: 35px auto 17px auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="[url]">
                <span class="name">Peter</span>
                <span class="more">More</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="[url]">
                <span class="name">Paul</span>
                <span class="more">More</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="[url]">                            
                <span class="name">Mary</span>
                <span class="more">More</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <div class="clear"></div>      
    </ul>
</div><!-- END: container -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SCRtb/

Comment: looks fine in IE7 compatible view, are you using stand alone IE7?

Comment: Using developer tools in IE8 and setting Browser Mode: IE7 + Document Mode: IE7 Standards - Also used netrenderer.com and tested browser IE7... Just trying to check all browser versions

Comment: It's probably because of the `display: block` declaration on `li`. You could try `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Tried that already - that's doesn't change anything